# using rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication - token expire after short time, and then the user have to login again

Tags: reactjs, django, jwt, access-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I new in WEB world and Authentication, and I got some problems.
I try to set JWT Authentication with Django and React, but even after I set this in django:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=20)
}
```

In the frontend side (my react app), I automatically disconnect after something like 30 min's,
and then I have to login again (and I set life time to 10 days!).

So im not sure what going there, and why the default value to 'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME' is 5 min?
who want to keep login and login again every 5 minutes? I think I don't understand something or miss something.
I've given up already and would appreciate some help - or some diffrent way to do Authentication with django-react app.

Just in case, here more configurations that are related:

```
DEFAULTS = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": False,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": False,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": settings.SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}
```

I tryed to set this:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=20)
}
```

And I expected that I will be required to verify with the password only be more 10 days, not 30 minutes.

Comment: try  deleting `"SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),`

Comment: Ok I think I understand the problem. The toucan really preserves its vitality. The problem is on the frontend side, apparently the cache has been deleted, I need to reconnect (with the same token)